# Recognition of Audio

Tags: java, audio, javasound, audio-analysis

I'm working on a program that shall record audio recognizable, so it can later be easily compared with other audio files. 
The audio files will contain something like speech, so I was wondering what would be easier to do:

- Implementing an algorithm for speech recognition and saving/comparing that outputs,
- or implementing / creating an algorithm that creates something like a audio-fingerprint with e.g. Fast Fourier Transform and compares those?

Has anyone some experience on that area? I'm wondering if the second solution would be realizable within a relatively short period of time. Maybe there is a solution that is less hard to code and I'm just not finding it?

Answer (score 1):

take a look at acoustic finger printing, most of the code you can find at github! it should help you solve your problem, more specifically the https://github.com/lalinsky/chromaprint/tree/master/tools

for more information take a look at this thread, this topic has already been extensively covered, [Open source audio pattern recognition (finger printing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269167/open-source-audio-pattern-recognition-finger-printing) and [Creating custom voice commands (GNU/Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304768/creating-custom-voice-commands-gnu-linux)